# VueJS emitted event not getting caught by other components in the same hierarchy

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vuejs2

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300634/emit-an-event-from-child-to-parent-in-vue-js-es6-syntax/40301449#40301449) and tried both the `this.$parent` and the `this.$root` alternatives, to no avail. The situation is as follows.

#### **`App.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <global-notifications/>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import GlobalNotifications from "./components/GlobalNotifications.vue"

export default {
    name: "app",
    components: {
        GlobalNotifications
    }
};
</script>
```

#### **`GlobalNotifications.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Notifications:</p>
        <p v-for="n in notifications" :key="n.id">{{ n }}</p>
        <b-button @click="internalEmitter">Internal notification!</b-button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            notifications: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        appendNotification(n) {
            this.notifications = [...this.notifications, n]
        },
        internalEmitter() {
            let message = { id: `${Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000)}`, message: 'From the inside!' }
            this.$emit('global-notification', message)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$on('global-notification', this.appendNotification)
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.$off('global-notification', this.appendNotification)
    }
}
</script>
```

#### **`Dashboard.vue`**

Gets loaded through the router. Yes, I tried loading it directly from `App.vue`.

```
<template>
    <b-button @click="emitTheThing">External notification!</b-button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        emitTheThing() {
            let message = { id: `${Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000)}`, message: 'From the outside!' }
            this.$emit('global-notification', message)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I click on the `Internal notification!` button, I get events fired and caught, and everything works as expected. However, when I click on the `External notification!` button, the only evidence of events flying around that I can see is in the Vue Dev Tools, where I see events being emitted.

As I said, I tried emitting on `$parent` and even on `$root`, but I only see  the events in the dev tools, being emitted on `<App>` and `<Root>`, respectively. However, the `GlobalNotification` child does not seem to catch them.

What am I missing?

Comment: Uses event bus should be one option. check [Vuejs setting up event bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745826/vuejs-setting-up-event-bus)

Comment: I thought about that but it sounded like an overkill to my ears. I will go down that route if there really are no other options, though.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `<global-notifications>` component listens for events on itself, while you're emitting the event on the root component. Note that emitting the event on a root component does **not** broadcast the event to the root's child components (as you've observed with Vue DevTools).

A quick fix in your case is to use `$root.$on()` so that it sets up the listener on the root component:

```
mounted() {
    // this.$on('global-notification', this.appendNotification)
    this.$root.$on('global-notification', this.appendNotification)
},
```

Then, you can use `$root.$emit()` from any component in any heirarchy to emit an event to the root component.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9xnnon179)

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks for the heads up on the demo. Fixed now. Regarding the second comment, the OP states `I tried emitting on $parent and even on $root`.

Comment: Hey. I hadn't thought of listening on `$root`, that's a good point, even if terrifying from an encapsulation point of view :) both this and the bus are good alternatives in such a simple case. I'll give it a thought and decide if I can live with this quick and dirty solution or if I need a more flexible approach!